# Is there anyway to perform a "deep save" in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my service I create a "root" object which has associations to many objects which in turn have associations to many more objects and so on.  Once the root object is completely built and ready to be saved I would like to call `save` on the root object and have all associated objects all the way down be saved as well.  Right now I have a recursive method called `deepSave` which does this.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you see any issue using the cascade save on the associations? All the associations should cascade save if they are properly associated. Can you cite an example of the root and its children?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the cascade save". If you mean "belongsTo" then I don't think I can safely use that. I'll add an example tomorrow, but if you imagine an XML document with many deep levels that is literally what my Grails domain is coming from.  So imagine the class `element` which hasMany `element` and also hasMany `attribute`.

Comment: I should have been more specific about using `belongsTo` or `cascade`, instead of pointing out superficially. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `belongsTo` GORM automatically defines the cascading for you. This means: If A `belongsTo` B then A will be saved when B is saved. However, it is possible to define cascading without using `belongsTo` (if this does not fit to your domain model):

```
class Author {    
  static hasMany = [books: Book]
  static mapping = { books cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' } 
}
```

You should have a look at the [cascade](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html) property provided by GORM. Additionaly the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive) provides more detailed information.

Comment: Ah, here is what I was missing.  An excerpt from [Understanding Cascading Updates and Deletes](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#cascades):  ***If you do not define belongsTo then no cascades will happen and you will have to manually save each object (except in the case of the one-to-many, in which case saves will cascade automatically if a new instance is in a hasMany collection).***  Some of my objects were not part of a `hasMany` collection.

Comment: Surprisingly (which is a disappointment) using my `deepSave` method which calls `save(validate: false)` on objects recursively is much faster than calling `save(deepValidate: false, validate: false)` on my "root" object.